# Gradle build finished with 22 warnings(s)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, warnings

I'm working in Android Studio, I finished my app and I generated signed APK, but when i install it the app stops unfortunately.

When i want to clean the project it shows 22 warnings in a file named R.java and this 22 lines can't be deleted because the file generally can't be edited.
In the log event, the system says that this warnings are some stings which haven't no translation.
I tried also to use my phone instead of android emulator in order to test the app but i encounter the same problem and the app crashes.
Can i solve this with stack trace and how ?[this is my build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlktj.png) 
[My main activity here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g88RG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to build.gradle:

```
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Hope it will help you...

Comment: I tried but it still the same thing ! How can i delete or edit a file R.java because i find all lines in it are no longer used.

Comment: When I build gradle it puts out this message :Gradle build finished with 22 warnings(s)

Comment: string'com_facebook_loginview_og_in_buttom_continue_f1gender' has no default translation , and 21 other like this.

Comment: @ Ousama Amhal  I have updated  my answer. Can you please check it and let me know your feedback

Comment: I think  we are extending comment section. if you have WhatsApp means ping to this no:+91-7200381108. We will check over there